# What are the different ways to call Init method of a ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I want to know how many ways are there by which `Init` method of `MvxViewModel` gets called.

I am aware of this only:

```
ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(params object[] parameters).
```

Is there any other way by which `Init` can be called?
Please answer me I would help to me debug the code in great deal.

Comment: can anyone atleast guide me from where i can get this knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Init method is getting called through `MvxViewModelExtensions.CallBundleMethods` which in turn is only called on place, which is in the [`MvxDefaultViewModelLocator`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs) then again in the Platform Specific ViewsContainer.

So yes, typically it would happen only on navigation between two `ViewModel`s.